# External HDD listed in call to diskutil, but not in Disk Utility ot Finder

Tags: finder, hard-drive, disk-utility, ntfs

My question is similar to [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/149067/external-hdd-can-be-seen-in-disk-utility-but-not-in-finder), except that my HDD does *not* appear in Disk Utility, nor Finder. The drive fell about a foot onto the floor. After that, I connected it, it mounted, and I started to load a game that is stored on it. During loading, my Mac crashed and rebooted without warning. Since then, it has not appeared. The only place the I see any sign of life is in terminal, after running `diskutil list`, of which the output is:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            427.5 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 45.4 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.4 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data BackupDrive             499.9 GB   disk2s2
```

The last entry, `/dev/disk2`, is the drive in question. The most promising suggestions over on the other question linked involve connecting the drive to a Windows machine, and troubleshooting from there. I may try that.

Running `diskutil info disk2s2` gives

```
Device Identifier:         disk2s2
   Device Node:               /dev/disk2s2
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk2

   Volume Name:               BackupDrive
   Mounted:                   No

   Partition Type:            Microsoft Basic Data
   File System Personality:   ExFAT
   Type (Bundle):             exfat
   Name (User Visible):       ExFAT
```

Interestingly, this is all the output that I get, and the command hangs after this much is printed. I don't get another prompt until Ctrl-C. This hanging also happens when getting `info` for the EFI volume `disk2s1`, but not for the whole disk (i.e. `diskutil info disk2` runs fine).

The commands

`diskutil mount disk2s2`

`diskutil mount readOnly disk2s2`

`diskutil verifyVolume disk2s2`

all hang without any output at all (unless I'm just inpatient; how long should these take?)

Comment: Time to replace the drive.  The HDD got some damage when it fell to the floor. If there is critical data (and no backup) you might be able to use disk recovery software or service.

Comment: Have you try, if it's possible, change the USB cable?